# How can I change the format used for <pubDate>?

Tags: feeds, 9

I'm using Drupal 9 to display a RSS feed with the Aggregator module. For the imported items, the date for `<pubDate>Wed, 24 Nov 2021 20:05:46 +0000</pubDate>` is showed as *2 months 3 weeks ago*.

The timestamp fields are already set to use the *long* format for the date, which is set to *M j, Y*.

There's no display settings for the Aggregator module. I'm trying to change it with a preprocess hook using the Drupal date formatter, but that doesn't work either.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_aggregator_feed().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_aggregator_feed(&$variables) {
  $variables['pubDate'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'long');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A preprocess function name doesn't start with *templateName*; that means that hook is not invoked. It if were invoked, `\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'long')` without initializing `$date` would cause a *PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The timestamp must be numeric.* error.

Comment: yes i know, i stubbed that in because i dont want my actual template name in this post

Comment: aside from the template name, how would i properly initialize the $date variable for this?

Comment: In that case, just use `mymodule_preprocess_aggregator_feed()` as hook name, and users will know that you aren't using the real module name, but replaced it with `mymodule`. You should also show code that works, or describe exactly in that the expected result is different from what you obtain. Saying *it doesn't work* for code that seems incomplete or uses variables without first initializing them doesn't make clear to the users what exactly you don't understand in achieving the described task.

Comment: ok. i changed it to mymodule. Are you able to actually help me figure out how to fix this or not? This is slightly out of my league which is why i posted in the first place